# Apple script-get cpu usage as integer value

Tags: osx-lion, applescript

In terminal we can use

```
top -l 2 -F -R | awk '/CPU usage/ && NR>5 {printf "%d", $7+0}'
```

to get the value of cpu usage how can i get the value as an integer in apple script?
i tried this

```
set usedSpace to (do shell script "top -l 2 -F -R | awk '/CPU usage/ && NR>5 {printf "%d", $7+0}'") as integer
```

and gor the error

> Expected “,” but found unknown token

then tried like this

```
set usedSpace to (do shell script "top -l 2 -F -R | awk '/CPU usage/ && NR>5 '; printf $5}") as integer
```

and got an error like this

> error "Can’t make \"CPU usage: 6.40% user, 5.41% sys, 88.17% idle  }\"
>   into type integer." number -1700 from "CPU usage: 6.40% user, 5.41%
>   sys, 88.17% idle  }" to integer

can anybody help me solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
set usedSpace to (do shell script "top -l 2 -F -R | awk '/CPU usage/ && NR>5 {printf \"%d\", $7+0}'") as integer
```

or

```
set usedSpace to (do shell script "top -l 2 -F -R | awk '/CPU usage/ && NR>5 '; printf $5}") as text
```

Comment: can you explain the syntax? I dont get it what i did wrong and y??Thanks it worked :)

Comment: You needed to escape the quotes around %d to be passed to the shell correctly.